# Incremental updates using browser cache

Tags: ajax, rest, http, caching, single-page-application

The client (an AngularJS application) gets rather big lists from the server. The lists may have hundreds or thousands of elements, which can mean a few megabytes uncompressed (and some users (admins) get much more data).

I'm not planning to let the client get partial results as sorting and filtering should not bother the server.

Compression works fine (factor of about 10) and as the lists don't change often, `304 NOT MODIFIED` helps a lot, too. But another important optimization is missing:

As a typical change of the lists are rather small (e.g., modifying two elements and adding a new one), transferring the changes only sounds like a good idea. I wonder how to do it properly.

Something like `GET` `/offer/123/items` should always return all the items in the offer number 123, right? Compression and 304 can be used here, but no incremental update. A request like `GET` `/offer/123/items?since=1495765733` sounds like the way to go, but then browser caching does not get used:

- either nothing has changed and the answer is empty (and caching it makes no sense)
- or something has changed, the client updates its state and does never ask for changes since 1495765733 anymore (and caching it makes even less sense)

Obviously, when using the "since" query, nothing will be cached for the "resource" (the original query gets used just once or not at all).

So I can't rely on the browser cache and I can only use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, which have a few downsides:

- it's limited to a few megabytes (the browser HTTP cache may be much bigger and gets handled automatically)
- I have to implement some replacement strategy when I hit the limit
- the browser cache stores already compressed data which I don't get (I'd have to re-compress them)
- it doesn't work for the users (admins) getting bigger lists as even a single list may already be over limit
- it gets emptied on logout (a customer's requirement)

Given that there's HTML 5 and HTTP 2.0, that's pretty unsatisfactory. What am I missing?

**Is it possible to use the browser HTTP cache together with incremental updates?**

Comment: Why not do the request in two phases? First, request the new ids, with an optionally `since` filter, not cacheable. Then, request full item list, including item details, by including the ids as query parameters, as full cacheable request.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I can't see how it helps. When I include all ids, then I fetch the whole list, which I need to avoid. When I include the new ids only, then I get a request I'll never ever need again as there'll be different new ids the next time.

Comment: Which language are you using server side to serve these requests?

Comment: @JoeCoder Java (embedded Jetty Servlet).

Answer (score 4):

I think there is one thing you are missing: in short, headers. What I'm thinking you could do and that would match (most) of your requirements, would be to:

- First `GET` `/offer/123/items` is done normally, nothing special.
- Subsequents `GET` `/offer/123/items` will be sent with a `Fetched-At: 1495765733` header, indicating your server when the initial request has been sent.

From this point on, two scenarios are possible.

- Either there is no change, and you can send the 304.
- If there is a change however, return the new items since the time stamp previously sent has headers, but set a `Cache-Control: no-cache` from your response.

This leaves you to the point where you can have incremental updates, with caching of the initial megabytes-sized elements.

There is still one drawback though, that the caching is only done once, it won't cache updates. You said that your lists are not updated often so it might already work for you, but if you really want to push this further, I could think of one more thing.

Upon receiving an incremental update, you could trigger in the background another request without the `Fetched-At` header that won't be used at all by your application, but will just be there to update your http cache. It should not be as bad as it sounds performance-wise since your framework won't update its data with the new one (and potentially trigger re-renders), the only notable drawback would be in term of network and memory consumption. On mobile it might be problematic, but it doesn't sounds like an app intended to be displayed on them anyway.

<sub>I absolutely don't know your use-case and will just throw that out there, but are you really sure that doing some sort of pagination won't work? Megabytes of data sounds a lot to display and process for normal humans ;)</sub>

Comment: Nice answer, indeed! Sure, nobody wants to see thousands of lines, but the client can filter and sort them, so the humans get what they can use. Pagination would work, but the client can do it pretty well without generating any traffic. And probably faster.

Comment: Thanks! I see, as long as it has been considered then it's a good thing, wanted to be sure.

Comment: Do we know that the browser doesn't consider `Cache-Control: no-cache` as an occassion to free some memory? If I was told not to cache a new version of something, I wouldn't keep the old one either. Actually, [sec14.9.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) doesn't even say that the response mustn't be stored. I guess, we'd need `no-store`, too. +++ I'll try it all out (I don't have to support all browsers, so it's doable), but it'll take some time.

Comment: That's a pretty good point, yes `no-store` might be a better bet then. I can't find anything regarding potential deletion upon receiving a non cacheable response (either with `no-store` or `no-cache`), to me both behavior would made sense, so I guess it might depend on the browser like you said

Answer (score 3):

I would ditch the request/response cycle entirely and move to a push model.
Specifically, **WebSockets**.

This is the standard technology used on financial trading websites serving tables of real-time ticker data.  Here is one such production application demonstrating the power of WebSockets:

https://www.poloniex.com/exchange#btc_eth

WebSocket applications have two types of state: global and user.  The above link will show three tables of global data.  When you're logged in, two aditional tables of user data are displayed at the bottom.

This is not HTTP; you won't be able to just slap this into a Java Servlet.  You'll need to run a separate process on your server which communicates over TCP.  The good news is, there are mature solutions readily available.  A Java-based solution with a very decent free licensing option, which includes both client and server APIs (and does integrate with Angular2) is [Lightstreamer](https://www.lightstreamer.com/).  They have a well-organized [demo page](https://demos.lightstreamer.com/) too.  There are also adapters available to integrate with your data sources.

You may be hesitant to ditch your existing servlet approach, but this will be less headaches in the long run, and scales marvelously.  HTTP polling, even with well-designed header-only requests, do not scale well with large lists which update frequently.

---------- **EDIT** ----------

Since the list updates are infrequent, WebSockets are probably overkill.  Based on the further details provided by comments on this answer, I would recommend a DOM-based, AJAX-updated sorter and filterer such as [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/), which has some built-in [options for caching](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html).  In order to reuse client data across sessions, ajax requests in the previous link should be modified to save the [current data in the table](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) to `localStorage` after every ajax request, and when the client starts a new session, populate the table with this data.  This will allow the plugin to manage the filtering, sorting, caching and browser-based persistence.

Comment: You're sidestepping my question, nonetheless, it's a good answer. It is possible to use servlets with websockets (I've never tried, but it shouldn't be hard). I was thinking about long polling as a less problematic (and less powerful) alternative to websockets. +++ Thank you for the links. I don't have any problem with ditching the servlet as there's single class isolating the remaining code from HTTP.

Comment: I am sidestepping your question.  It's like when I answer questions about "how do i sync two lists?" and suggest a hashmap instead. :)

Comment: Yeah I guess Tomcat did shoehorn a WebSockets implementation into a Servlet, with an HTTP adapter.  Be warned that its a poor fit.  Read their warning about production usage: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html

Comment: Sure, sidestepping the question is sometimes the best thing. It's pretty impressive, but probably an overkill (my lists are big and I don't want to show stale data, but updates are rare). I'll read it and come back later, thank you. +++ Btw., it does not solve the caching problem: As I left the sorting and filtering to the client, it needs to load or cache a few megabytes of data.

Comment: It solves a different problem, namely propagating many changes to small lists on many clients fast. My problem is getting there a big list, which usually differs only slightly from its previous version. This comes from my uncommon decisions to let the client do all the sorting and filtering. Lightstreamer's clients never store megabytes of data as they get fed only by the data to be shown to the user. Their data change very fast, so it makes no sense to send and store more than can be displayed. I'd have to change a lot if I wanted to use Lightstreamer; it's doable, but then there's the price.

Comment: Why are you maintaining state on both the server and client?  Does data change along some non-independent variable other than time?  Unless you're planning on allowing browsing and/or reinsertion of expired data, I don't see why you wouldn't maintain state on server, and delegate sorting and filtering to a DOM-based sorter such as the jQuery plugin tablesorter.js.

Comment: I don't get this part of the question, but there are no expired data re-insertions and no special things like this. I do maintain the state on the server, but when I want the user to see the first 20 items from a list of 10000 while respecting their sorting and filtering and when I want to let the client do the sorting and filtering, then I need to get all the 10000 items to the client. Usually, the client fetched them all yesterday, and now I want to send to it only the 100 items which have changed since then. This assumes that the old state sits in the browser cache....

Comment: ... This works, but tomorrow, I'd like to build upon the state from today, but today there was no request for the full list, only the incremental update. So I could use the state of yesterday plus the 100 changes from today and send the 100 new changes. This doesn't look good as in a few days, I get 1000+100+100+100... I'd be happy if I could tell the browser to incorporate the changes in the original list as if I sent the whole list.

Comment: I've updated my answer since I better understand the requirement now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking about something similar to Aperçu's idea, but using two requests. The idea is yet incomplete, so bear with me...

- The client asks for `GET` `/offer/123/items`, possibly with the `ETag` and `Fetched-At` headers.

The server answers with

- `200` and a full list if either header is missing, or when there are too many changes since the `Fetched-At` timestamp
- `304` if nothing has changed since then
- *`304` and a special `Fetch-More` header* telling the client that more data is to be fetched otherwise

The last case is violating how HTTP should work, but AFAIK it's the only way letting the browser cache *everything* what I want it to cache. Since the whole communication is encrypted, proxies can't punish me for violating the spec.

The client reacts to `Fetch-Errata` by requesting `GET` `/offer/123/items/errata`. This way, the resource has got split into two requests. The split is ugly, but an angular $http interceptor can hide the ugliness from the application.

The second request is cacheable, too, and there can be also a `Fetched-At` header. The details are unclear, but some strong handwavium makes me believe that it can work. Actually, the errata could itself be inaccurate but still useful and get an errata itself.... etc.

With HTTP/1.1, more requests may mean more latency, but having a couple of them should still be profitable because of the saved bandwidth. The server can decide when to stop.

With HTTP/2, multiple requests could be send at once. The server could be make to handle them efficiently as it knows that they belong together. Some more handwavium...

*I find the idea strange, but interesting and I'm looking forward to comments. Feel free to downvote me, but please leave an explanation.*